# Can't add a specific number of an item after a command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm building a little shop for a map I'm doing and I'm trying to detect if the player has a certain number of gold nuggets on them. It works, but only for 1. I want it to check more than 1 item, I've tried numerous ways with the count command after it and none of them work. This is the command

```
execute if entity @p[nbt={Inventory:[id:"minecraft:gold_nugget"}]}]
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this isn't doable, unless you individually take them out of the users inventory and replace them.

Comment: would there be a way to do that?

Comment: Well, I upvoted the question, maybe someone more experienced will be able to find your answer.

Comment: Okay, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like:

- `/execute if entity @p[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:gold_nugget",Count:1b}]}] run COMMAND`

And change the value in `Count:#b` to the desired amount, but this only works if you are looking for the EXACT amount of an item.

If you want it to target a player with 1 or more gold nuggets, you will have to use a scoreboard:

- `/scoreboard objectives add gold_nuggets dummy`
  *(This is used to store the amount of gold nuggets players have.)* [You only have to run this once]
- `execute as @a store result score @s gold_nuggets run clear @s minecraft:gold_nugget 0` *(This stores the actually amount of gold nuggets each player has into the scoreboard (doesn't actually clear any items).)* [You should put this in a repeating command block]
- `execute if entity @p[scores={gold_nuggets=1..}] run COMMAND` *(This is used to see if a player has 1 or more gold nuggets in their inventory.)* [You should use one of these for each shop trade, just change the value of `gold_nuggets=1..`]

Comment: Thank you so much, now I just need to set up the reduction system when you buy something. I think I could figure it out but is there a certain command that would do that after you bought something?